# Grouping a data frame and using apply

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, tapply

I currently have a data frame that looks like this...

```
Year           School     AveragePoints     
2012-2013     Alabama        2.5
2012-2013     Alabama        5.4
2012-2013     Alabama        10.4
2012-2013     Alabama        1.2
2012-2013     Alabama        9.2
2012-2013     Alabama        7.3
```

Each row represents a player on that team for that year.  So the first row means that one player on Alabama for 2012-2013 averaged 2.5 points that year.  The data frame is much longer than this, with more teams and the years continuing through 1997-1998.  I want to know how to find out how many players averaged between 0-4, 4.1-9, 9.1-14, and >14.1 for each year per school.  In other words for 2012-2013, how many players averaged in those 4 categories for Alabama.  But I would need those numbers for each year for Alabama and the other schools involved.   I think some form of an apply function should be used but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should look into `cut` first, and then into `aggregate` (or `tapply`) or possibly even `table`.

Here's how I would proceed:

Add a column with the `cut` results.

```
mydf$AP <- with(mydf, cut(AveragePoints, c(0, 4.1, 9.1, 14.1)))
```

Here's a `table` approach:

```
table(mydf[c("AP", "Year", "School")])
# , , School = Alabama
# 
#             Year
# AP           2012-2013
#   (0,4.1]            2
#   (4.1,9.1]          2
#   (9.1,14.1]         2
```

However, the output for `aggregate` would probably be a much more useful format.

```
aggregate(. ~ Year + School + AP, mydf, length)
#        Year  School         AP AveragePoints
# 1 2012-2013 Alabama    (0,4.1]             2
# 2 2012-2013 Alabama  (4.1,9.1]             2
# 3 2012-2013 Alabama (9.1,14.1]             2
```